# Identifying a salvaged HD BLDC motor

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

I need a motor that can deliver 500 to 4000 RPM unloaded. I figured I could salvage one from an old HD, and now I have one. It has 4 wires, and I measure 25ohms from any two points I measure.

From that can anybody tell me how it is wound, and how I should drive it from a microcontroller?

Comment: Are you *sure* that any two wires give 25 ohms? A stepper motor will have two coils, each having similar (25 ohm) resistance, but infinite resistance from one coil to the other.

Comment: In theory, I could see a four-ended wye winding doing that, though the only examples I'm familiar with would be unipolar steppers which would have a fifth lead to the common point. As for how you should drive it from a microcontroller, only through a suitable driver/amplifier circuit. Realistically, put this back in the junk box, go to an online radio control hobby supplier and select a motor suitable to your application, along with a suitable driver verified by online research to have an open-source alternative firmware you can modify to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Being from an old hard drive it is probably wound in Star (Wye) configuration, with the enter tap brought out to provide a back-emf reference. This was required by some early sensorless controller ICs such as the [TDA5140A](http://www.bucek.name/pdf/tda5140.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can connect 6 coils to achieve what you are measuring but it seems a bit unlikely to me.  It would be a box configuration with a coil on each side and a coil on each diagonal.

Popular brush less motors usually use a star ("Y") or delta connection to match common motor driver ICs.

Many brushless DC motor drivers could drive your motor but more would not.  You should try to find one that has ratings similar to what you expect your motor to work at.

Comment: Well, you could connect 4 coils in star to get the same measurement as well, to be picky.

Comment: @IanBland, no so.  You would measure differently from the middle node to the branches as opposed to between two branches.  I do suspect that this is what the OP has and failed to test or describe correctly but it is not the same as a regular 4 node arrangement.